# How to echo nested json in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

How to ech

```
[{"date":"2020-05-01","stats":[{"metrics":{"blocks":118,"bounce_drops":80,"bounces":148,"clicks":2642,"deferred":716,"delivered":73681,"invalid_emails":2,"opens":8072,"processed":67638,"requests":74028,"spam_report_drops":0,"spam_reports":2,"unique_clicks":1510,"unique_opens":4274,"unsubscribe_drops":0,"unsubscribes":0}}]}]
```

but i am not sure how i can echo certain value, i have created a code, but it doesn't work.

I just want to echo specific terms, like requests.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$response = "[{"date":"2020-05-01","stats":[{"metrics":{"blocks":118,"bounce_drops":80,"bounces":148,"clicks":2642,"deferred":716,"delivered":73681,"invalid_emails":2,"opens":8072,"processed":67638,"requests":74028,"spam_report_drops":0,"spam_reports":2,"unique_clicks":1510,"unique_opens":4274,"unsubscribe_drops":0,"unsubscribes":0}}]}]";

$json = json_decode($response,true);
foreach ($json['stats']['metrics']['requests'] as $person) {
  echo $person;
}
$characters = json_decode($response, true); // decode the JSON feed
foreach ( $characters as $stats => $array ) {   
    $characters = $array['requests'];
  echo $array['requests'];
  echo $characters;
}
  echo $array['requests'];
  echo $characters;
?>
```

Comment: $response is an Array, you should access `metrics` it like this `foreach ($json[0]['stats'][0]['metrics'] as $person) {`

Comment: @ROOT then i have to have `echo $person[requests];` ?

Comment: if you want to access it directly, just use `$json[0]['stats'][0]['metrics']['requests']` without looping through response.

Comment: @ROOT that throws out error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: you should not use loop if you want to access it directly: check this: https://3v4l.org/N07rr

Comment: That works, please make it an answer :D i will mark it.

Comment: I can't because  your question is closed :) since it was posted, you can support me with upvates on other answer :P